# Omit unused XML elements during XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to transform XML document using XSLT. Some elements from original XML document is unused in my XSL document, but values of these elements are added to the result. How can I omit such elements? Example:

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Test</name>
    <description>Test description</description>
</data>
```

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="id">
        <id>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </id>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result

```
<id>1</id>TestTest description
```

Expected result

```
<id>1</id>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is the result of the [built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#built-in-rule) that copy text nodes as the default.

The simplest way to prevent this is to be more specific - for example, do:

```
<xsl:template match="/data">
    <xsl:copy-of select="id"/>
</xsl:template>
```